# how to extract a word from string using substring function in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, substring, grafana

This is the string:atlngahpig001_to_atlngahpig002-GatewayCallStats
from which I need to extract  atlngahpig001
In place of altnagahpig001 there may be someother

Can anyone find a solution how to get it using substring function?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends how you want to look for the string but you can do this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('atlngahpig001_to_atlngahpig002-GatewayCallStats', 1, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more generic solution assuming the string format is consistent, you can use,

```
SELECT split_part('atlngahpig001_to_atlngahpig002-GatewayCallStats', '_', 1);
```

Comment: "I used following substring select  substring("INSTANCE_ID" from '%_to_#"_%#"-%' for '#') from which it extracts atlngahpig002, here "INSTANCE_ID" -atlngahpig001_to_atlngahpig002-GatewayCallStats ,but i need to extract   this "atlngahpig001 " i,.e first word ,can you help me out?

Comment: select substring('atlngahpig001_to_atlngahpig002-GatewayCallStats' from '#"_%#"_to_%-%' for '#')